# Handle multiple process request in Django with Gunicorn server

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I just want to know is it possible to run and handle multiple processes in Django when i am using gunicorn server.

If one client is requesting for data and at the same time other client request the same then both process should be executed simultaneous instead of queue.

Is there any other way to make this happen.?

Answer (score 2):

You can start multiple worker processes:

```
gunicorn -w 4 ...
```

That would create 4 processes which each can handle one request at a time.

You could also use a different worker type, like `gevent` or `meinheld`, to make gunicorn handle requests asynchronously:

```
gunicorn --worker-class=gevent ...
gunicorn --worker-class="egg:meinheld#gunicorn_worker" ...
```

For those last two, you need to either install [gevent](https://github.com/SiteSupport/gevent/downloads) (one of the rc versions) or [meinheld](http://meinheld.org/).

Comment: 2013-03-27 02:54:26 [4575] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7454)

Comment: Standard configuration for worker timeouts is 30 seconds, if your workers are taking more time than that (though if they do, I wonder why...) you need to raise that using `-t`. You can also start gunicorn using `--log-level=debug` to get more information.

Comment: I am getting this error as the request cannot be completed in 30sec: 2013-03-27 02:54:26 [4575] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7454)
The server can have multiple request and fetching that data can take time which is undefined. I cant define the --timeout as i dont know the time required as the data is been fetched from other server through telnet.

Comment: In that case, you should set the timeout to some really large value (I don't know, one day or something) *and* use one of the asynchronous worker types (which are much better in handling I/O which might take a long time to complete).